# How do I combine SQL Server coalesce, sum and subquery to get a single returned row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, coalesce

These two SQL selects work independently, but I need help combining them into a single select statement to produce one single row with all the fields from both queries.

Select #1:

```
select 
    'F' row_type, 
    sum(movement.override_pay_amt_n + tmp.b) as total_amount 
from 
    movement, 
    (select coalesce(sum(driver_extra_pay.amount_n),0.0) b 
     from driver_extra_pay,deduct_code,movement 
     where driver_extra_pay.company_id = 'tms' 
       and driver_extra_pay.movement_id = 1
       and driver_extra_pay.movement_id = movement.id 
       and driver_extra_pay.payee_id = movement.override_payee_id 
       and movement.company_id = 'tms' 
       and code_type = 'E' 
       and deduct_code.id = driver_extra_pay.deduct_code_id 
       and deduct_code.company_id = 'tms') tmp 
where 
    movement.id = 1
    and movement.company_id = 'tms'
```

Select #2:

```
select 
    'BBS' row_type, 
    movement.override_pay_amt, 
    override_pay_amt as total_amount, 
    movement.override_pay_amt_n,
    movement.override_pay_amt_d,
    movement.override_pay_amt_c,
    movement.override_pay_amt_r
from 
    movement 
where 
    movement.id = 1 
    and movement.company_id = 'tms' ;
```

My combined select:

```
select 
    'BBSALL' row_type, 
    movement.override_pay_amt, 
    override_pay_amt as total_amount, 
    movement.override_pay_amt_n,
    movement.override_pay_amt_d,
    movement.override_pay_amt_c,
    movement.override_pay_amt_r,
    sum(movement.override_pay_amt_n + tmp.b) as total_amount 
from 
    movement, 
    (select coalesce(sum(driver_extra_pay.amount_n),0.0) b 
     from driver_extra_pay,deduct_code,movement 
     where driver_extra_pay.company_id = 'tms' 
       and driver_extra_pay.movement_id = 1
       and driver_extra_pay.movement_id = movement.id 
       and driver_extra_pay.payee_id = movement.override_payee_id 
       and movement.id = 1 
       and movement.company_id = 'tms' 
       and code_type = 'E' 
       and deduct_code.id = driver_extra_pay.deduct_code_id 
       and deduct_code.company_id = 'tms') tmp
```

But I get this error....

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 48
>   Column 'movement.override_pay_amt' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: try change `sum` to sum(movement.override_pay_amt_n + tmp.b) over () as total_amount`, moreover, you should have a join condition ...

Comment: You really need to start using ANSI-92 style joins. They have been available for more than 25 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins And add some formatting to your code so you can read it. There is not an award for least amount of characters. Adding some aliases would help considerably as well.

Comment: @SeanLange - this is legacy code that is not mine.  I am simply trying to get a problem fixed.  Once it's fixed, I'll refactor the code.  Today does not provide time such things.

Comment: @RadimBača can you provide an example of the JOIN, that is where I am stuck.

Comment: LOL. There is never time allotted to go back and make code better. The time to fix it is when you are in the middle of it. Given that you are struggling to fix it maybe this is the time. Too many developers get stuck in this mindset of fixing code right now, if you fixed the code right this would be a lot easier both now and the next time somebody has to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the grouping, assuming you want the results summarised.

```
SELECT  'BBSALL' row_type
,       movement.override_pay_amt
,       override_pay_amt AS total_amount
,       movement.override_pay_amt_n
,       movement.override_pay_amt_d
,       movement.override_pay_amt_c
,       movement.override_pay_amt_r
,       SUM(movement.override_pay_amt_n + tmp.b) AS total_amount
FROM    movement
,       (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(driver_extra_pay.amount_n), 0.0) b
         FROM   driver_extra_pay
         ,      deduct_code
         ,      movement
         WHERE  driver_extra_pay.company_id = 'tms'
                AND driver_extra_pay.movement_id = 1
                AND driver_extra_pay.movement_id = movement.id
                AND driver_extra_pay.payee_id = movement.override_payee_id
                AND movement.id = 1
                AND movement.company_id = 'tms'
                AND code_type = 'E'
                AND deduct_code.id = driver_extra_pay.deduct_code_id
                AND deduct_code.company_id = 'tms'
        ) tmp     
GROUP BY row_type
,       movement.override_pay_amt
,       override_pay_amt
,       movement.override_pay_amt_n
,       movement.override_pay_amt_d
,       movement.override_pay_amt_c
,       movement.override_pay_amt_r
```

Comment: i tried your solution, but get a syntax error when trying to group by the row-type.  I don't think it is supported as you've described in ms sql server.  Unless i've missed something.

Comment: Have edited. give it another go, see what you get.  without your tables etc, couldn't test it and made newbie mistake!